# Normalize array of json records into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from the owid covid19 json data located [here](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/README.md).
The json has an array of daily records in the data column, this along with the country index is what I'm trying to make into a dataframe.

```
{"AFG":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":39835428.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6,"aged_65_older":2.581,"aged_70_older":1.337,"gdp_per_capita":1803.987,"cardiovasc_death_rate":597.029,"diabetes_prevalence":9.59,"handwashing_facilities":37.746,"hospital_beds_per_thousand":0.5,"life_expectancy":64.83,"human_development_index":0.511,"data":[{"date":"2020-02-24","total_cases":5.0,"new_cases":5.0,"total_cases_per_million":0.126,"new_cases_per_million":0.126,"stringency_index":8.33},{"date":"2020-02-25","total_cases":5.0,"new_cases":0.0,"total_cases_per_million":0.126,"new_cases_per_million":0.0,"stringency_index":8.33},
```

So far I've been loading the file straight into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_json('owid-covid-data.json', orient='index')
```

and then normalizing the array as such

```
data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(key)) for key in df['data']])
```

Which works fine apart from dropping the index and thus giving no identifier to join back to the static values.

I also imagine there's a more efficient way of normalizing than what I've used.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  Your second character is an open parenthesis, which is not allowed, and you're using single quotes instead of double quotes.  Is this just the Python representation of your data?

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah apologies that was the Python representation, updated now

Comment: Your data are a list of dict like `[{"AFG": ...}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_json("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json", orient='index')

# explode records/ lists into new rows, convert to dict, 
# use it to create a new DataFrame, and transpose it
data = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].explode().to_dict()).T

df = df.drop(columns='data').join(data)
```

**Performance**

Ignoring the data reading

```
>>> %%timeit
... data = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].explode().to_dict()).T
... df.drop(columns='data').join(data)

84.4 ms ± 3.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**EDIT - DISCLAIMER**

The above solution is actually wrong. During the `to_dict` conversion many records are lost because there are lots of repeated country codes keys (Series index), and keys of a dictionary must be unique. To solve this, first, we need to reset the index to make sure it's unique. Only after the new DataFrame is created, we add the original index.

```
data = df['data'].explode()
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data.reset_index(drop=True).to_dict()).T
data_df.index = data.index

df = df.drop(columns='data').join(data_df)
```

This is much slower than the previous solution because there are actually 127314 records, while the previous solution only produces 233 records (unique country codes). Even if we ignore the `join` part, as Bruno's solution does, it's much slower than Bruno's solution

```
>>> %%timeit 
... data = df['data'].explode()
... new_df = pd.DataFrame(data.reset_index(drop=True).to_dict()).T
... new_df.index = data.index

17.6 s ± 972 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# Bruno's solution 
>>> %%timeit
... country_codes = []
... datas = []
... for index, data in zip(df.index, df['data']):
...     datas.extend(data)
...     country_codes.extend(len(data)*[index])
...     
... new_df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
... new_df['country_code'] = country_codes

1.86 s ± 32.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**EDIT 2 - There is a better way...**

I found a much better and simpler solution. I was definitely overcomplicating.  It's basically the same idea as Bruno's solution

```
data = df['data'].explode()
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), index=data.index)

df = df.drop(columns='data').join(data_df)
```

It's as fast as Bruno's solution

```
>>> %%timeit 
... data = df['data'].explode()
... pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), index=data.index)

1.87 s ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: how's the performance compared to Bruno's?

Comment: @sammywemmy I have updated my answer. It's much faster.

Comment: it would be a good comparison if you ran bruno's on your end as well, so the timings can be a bit more comparable

Comment: @sammywemmy You are right, good point! Give me a second

Comment: @sammywemmy actually I found out my solution is incorrect. During the dict conversion the repeated country keys and info are lost. I will update it soon.

Comment: @sammywemmy updated the solution. It's actually much slower...

Comment: best performance will likely be within dictionaries, before reading into Pandas. that might mean avoiding reading the data with pd.read_json, and just use maybe requests

Comment: @sammywemmy I actually found a simpler solution. I agree with you. Probably I would read the data with `json` module and pass it to `pd.json_normalize` to normalize it one go.

Comment: Awesome solution! Much more concise than mine

Answer (score 3):

It's not the most efficient way, but it works:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tmp = pd.json_normalize(row['data'])
    tmp['country_code'] = index
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, tmp])
```

EDIT:

I found a more efficient way, by normalizing all the JSONs at once:

```
country_codes = []
datas = []
for index, data in zip(df.index, df['data']):
    datas.extend(data)
    country_codes.extend(len(data)*[index])
    
new_df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
new_df['country_code'] = country_codes
```

Improved from `9.38 s ± 856 ms per loop` to `1.37 s ± 12 ms per loop`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.json_normalize()` which is must faster(*I tried this out on the entire JSON file*):

```
%%timeit
pd.json_normalize(
    data["AFG"],
    record_path=["data"],
    meta=[
        "continent",
        "location",
        "population",
        "population_density",
        "median_age",
        "aged_65_older",
        "aged_70_older",
        "gdp_per_capita",
        "cardiovasc_death_rate",
        "diabetes_prevalence",
        "handwashing_facilities",
        "hospital_beds_per_thousand",
        "life_expectancy",
        "human_development_index",
    ],
)

17.9 ms ± 1.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Output:**

```
 date  total_cases  new_cases  total_cases_per_million  new_cases_per_million  stringency_index  new_cases_smoothed  ...  gdp_per_capita  cardiovasc_death_rate  diabetes_prevalence  handwashing_facilities  hospital_beds_per_thousand  life_expectancy  human_development_index
0    2020-02-24          5.0        5.0                    0.126                  0.126              8.33                 NaN  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
1    2020-02-25          5.0        0.0                    0.126                  0.000              8.33                 NaN  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
2    2020-02-26          5.0        0.0                    0.126                  0.000              8.33                 NaN  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
3    2020-02-27          5.0        0.0                    0.126                  0.000              8.33                 NaN  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
4    2020-02-28          5.0        0.0                    0.126                  0.000              8.33                 NaN  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
..          ...          ...        ...                      ...                    ...               ...                 ...  ...             ...                    ...                  ...                     ...                         ...              ...                      ...
610  2021-10-26     156071.0       31.0                 3917.894                  0.778               NaN              38.571  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
611  2021-10-27     156124.0       53.0                 3919.225                  1.330               NaN              37.857  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
612  2021-10-28     156166.0       42.0                 3920.279                  1.054               NaN              39.286  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
613  2021-10-29     156196.0       30.0                 3921.032                  0.753               NaN              37.857  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511
614  2021-10-30     156210.0       14.0                 3921.384                  0.351               NaN              38.571  ...        1803.987                597.029                 9.59                  37.746                         0.5            64.83                    0.511

[615 rows x 38 columns]
```

But the fastest solution is just downloading the data in `csv` format, as they give you the link [here](https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv).

Comment: how did you load the json file before executing pd.json_noramlize?

Comment: @Rabinzel I made a GET request to the [link](https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json).

Comment: thanks. Since you have a lot of reputation here, I guess you can help me. What is the general approach on stackoverflow if I have a question on my own but quite connected to this post and not that much of different. I want to solve the OP's problem a little differently and I can't figure it out. Do I ask here in the comments or start a new topic with a link to this post?

Comment: @Rabinzel if its very similar it will probably get marked as a duplicate. If you want to solve it then you will have to come up with the solution, no one can help you there.